# Java simplifying draw object pathways

Tags: java, methods, functional-interface

So, basically, I'm trying to make a Functional Interface so that I can just pick between different draw operations, and not have to write out the actual variables passed to each one. I have this:

```
public void draw(Graphics g){
    setColor(g);
    Consumer4 c;
    //if (getSolid()) g.fillOval(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    //else g.drawOval(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    if (getSolid()) c = (int t,int u,int v,int w) -> g.fillOval(t,u,v,w);
    else c = (t,u,v,w) -> g.drawOval(t,u,v,w);
    g.c(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
}
```

and I made this class to help it out: (note it is located in an abstract superclass)

```
    @FunctionalInterface
    protected static interface Consumer4{
        //public abstract <T,U,V,W>void accept(T t,U u,V v,W w);
        public abstract void accept(int t,int u,int v,int w);
    }
```

The commented out part is what I want it to do, also note that I was trying to do it with generics, hence the commented out part of my functional interface.

I also tried this to see if it would help, along with the associated changes in my Functional Interface, but no luck.

```
    if (getSolid()) c = (int t,int u,int v,int w,Graphics y) -> y.fillOval(t,u,v,w);
    else c = (t,u,v,w,y) -> y.drawOval(t,u,v,w);
    c(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height,g);
```

Is this doable? Or what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, I figured it out...

```
        if (getSolid()) c = (int t,int u,int v,int w) -> g.fillOval(t,u,v,w);
        else c = (t,u,v,w) -> g.drawOval(t,u,v,w);
        c.accept(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
```

though, no matter how I think about it, it seems like more code than it's worth, unless c gets used multiple times.